# Batch renaming files using UNIX - should I use awk?

Tags: bash, unix, awk, renaming

I have a large number of image files that i need to rename from the comand line. I believe the best way to do this is to use awk (please correct if this is incorrect).

file names are like the following

```
1038282829128738912-1.jpg
```

Every image file starts with '103' and I want to replace this part of the file name with '201003' - leaving the rest intact ... eg.

```
2010038282829128738912-1.jpg
```

The images are in multiple folders under one main folder (images) - but it would be handy for all the images to be copied into one folder (images_renamed)

I don't know where to start with this - and I have googled for awk usage but can only find examples of renaming text *inside* files.

Any help appreciated. Thanks/

Comment: The Perl `rename` script does this job handily. Indeed, one of the motivations for writing Perl was awk's limited support for many files.
`rename` should already be part of debian based distros or http://search.cpan.org/~rmbarker/File-Rename-0.05/

Comment: Thanks for all your answers - I'm going to do some reading and try some of these out.

I'll come back later and mark the question answered - I'm sure there must be some correct answers in here :-) thanks again.

Comment: check here:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/bulk-renaming-of-files-in-unix.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have the `rename` command on your UNIX, you should be able to use something like:

```
mkdir images_renamed
cd images_renamed
cp ../103*.jpg .
rename 103 201003 *.jpg
```

The `rename FROM TO FILE` will rename all the files specified by `FILE`, changing the first occurrence of `FROM` to `TO`.

If that's not available, you can use something like:

```
mkdir images_renamed
for fspec in 103*.jpg ; do
    cp ${fspec} images_renamed/201003${fspec:3}
done
```

To do this recursively, I would put it into a script with `find`:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

rm -rf images_renamed
ls -lR images
echo

cd images
find . -name '*.jpg' | while read -r; do
    mkdir -p "../images_renamed/$(dirname "$REPLY")"
    echo 'Copying from' [$REPLY]
    echo '          to' [../images_renamed/$REPLY] and renaming.
    echo
    cp "$REPLY" "../images_renamed/$REPLY"
    cd "$(dirname "../images_renamed/$REPLY")"
    rename 103 201003 "$(basename "$REPLY")"
    cd - >/dev/null
done

cd ..
ls -lR images_renamed
```

Only the middle bit of that is required, the rest is for testing. The output below shows how it works, copying across every file to the new directory structure and renaming the relevant files.

```
images:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 pax None 0 2010-08-12 20:55 dir1
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 pax None 0 2010-08-12 20:55 dir2
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 pax None 0 2010-08-12 20:56 dir3

images/dir1:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 pax None 0 2010-08-12 20:55 102xxx.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 pax None 0 2010-08-12 20:55 103xxx.jpg

images/dir2:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 pax None 0 2010-08-12 20:55 103yyy.jpg

images/dir3:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 pax None 0 2010-08-12 20:55 dir 4

images/dir3/dir 4:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 pax None 0 2010-08-12 20:55 103zzz.jpg

Copying from [./dir1/102xxx.jpg]
          to [../images_renamed/./dir1/102xxx.jpg] and renaming.

Copying from [./dir1/103xxx.jpg]
          to [../images_renamed/./dir1/103xxx.jpg] and renaming.

Copying from [./dir2/103yyy.jpg]
          to [../images_renamed/./dir2/103yyy.jpg] and renaming.

Copying from [./dir3/dir 4/103zzz.jpg]
          to [../images_renamed/./dir3/dir 4/103zzz.jpg] and renaming.

images_renamed:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 pax None 0 2010-08-12 21:19 dir1
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 pax None 0 2010-08-12 21:19 dir2
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 pax None 0 2010-08-12 21:19 dir3

images_renamed/dir1:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 pax None 0 2010-08-12 21:19 102xxx.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 pax None 0 2010-08-12 21:19 201003xxx.jpg

images_renamed/dir2:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 pax None 0 2010-08-12 21:19 201003yyy.jpg

images_renamed/dir3:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 pax None 0 2010-08-12 21:19 dir 4

images_renamed/dir3/dir 4:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 pax None 0 2010-08-12 21:19 201003zzz.jpg
```

---

To flatten the file hierarchy, you can use something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

rm -rf images_renamed
ls -lR images
echo

cd images
mkdir -p ../images_renamed
find . -name '*.jpg' | while read -r; do
    newfile="$(basename "$REPLY")"
    echo 'Copying from' [$REPLY]
    echo '          to' [../images_renamed/$newfile] and renaming.
    echo
    cp "$REPLY" "../images_renamed/$newfile"
    cd ../images_renamed
    rename 103 201003 "$newfile"
    cd - >/dev/null
done
```

which outputs:

```
cd ..
ls -lR images_renamed
images:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 allan None 0 2010-08-12 20:55 dir1
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 allan None 0 2010-08-12 20:55 dir2
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 allan None 0 2010-08-12 20:56 dir3

images/dir1:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 allan None 0 2010-08-12 20:55 102xxx.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 allan None 0 2010-08-12 20:55 103xxx.jpg

images/dir2:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 allan None 0 2010-08-12 20:55 103yyy.jpg

images/dir3:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 allan None 0 2010-08-12 20:55 dir 4

images/dir3/dir 4:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 allan None 0 2010-08-12 20:55 103zzz.jpg

Copying from [./dir1/102xxx.jpg]
          to [../images_renamed/102xxx.jpg] and renaming.

Copying from [./dir1/103xxx.jpg]
          to [../images_renamed/103xxx.jpg] and renaming.

Copying from [./dir2/103yyy.jpg]
          to [../images_renamed/103yyy.jpg] and renaming.

Copying from [./dir3/dir 4/103zzz.jpg]
          to [../images_renamed/103zzz.jpg] and renaming.

images_renamed:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 allan None 0 2010-08-12 22:41 102xxx.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 allan None 0 2010-08-12 22:41 201003xxx.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 allan None 0 2010-08-12 22:41 201003yyy.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 allan None 0 2010-08-12 22:41 201003zzz.jpg
```

but you need to keep in mind that filename clashes (the same file name under different directories) will overwrite each other.

Comment: No, you need a find wrapped around it. Updated to show one way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The only thing I would want to change is the destination. Instead of retaining the directory structure where the files were copied from - I want all the images to be copied to the 'images_renamed' folder. I've tried changing the script you provided but no sucess. I cant work out the relationship between $REPLY and dirname, basename etc. I can tell that $REPLY is the ful path and filename that the find command matches - but can I extract only the filename from this information for use in the rename step (ie. using only the filename, not the directory)

Comment: You're a star - thanks. I actually got to this last bit '$(basename $REPLY)' - just after I posted so I've learned something i guess.

Answer (score 0):

In ZSH you can do this (probably works in Bash too, not sure about this):

```
for f in **/103*.jpg; mv $f some_other_directory/201003${${f:t}#103}
```

Maybe I can also interest you in a tool I wrote: http://github.com/jkramer/virn
It allows you to mass-rename files using Vim, including all of Vims features like regex etc. (Actually, you can use any other $EDITOR as well).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could help:

```
cd images
find . -name '*.jpg' | while read -r img; do
    mkdir -p "../images_renamed/$(dirname "$img")"
    cp -v "$img" "../images_renamed/$(echo "$img" | sed -e 's/^103/201003/')"
done
```

Note: Not tested. Should not delete things though.

Comment: Do you really want to make a directory for each file?

Comment: That’s not what I do. I take the original file name (including directory) and create that directory and possible directories above it. You might want to read that line again.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
ls -d images*
images/          images_renamed/


for i in `find images -type f`
do
  cp $i images_renamed/$(basename $i | sed s/^103/201003/)
done
```

Comment: Doesn't work if filenames contain spaces. Use `find | while read` and quote variables that contain filenames.

Comment: agreed, but didn't feel the need to do so based on the OP's filename convention.

Answer (score 0):

```
find /path -type f -name "10*jpg" | sed 's/.*/mv &/' | sed 's/mv \(.*\/\)\(.[^/]*\)/& \120\2/' | sh
```

Answer (score -1):

haven't tested but something like this could work in bash:

```
for i in `ls 103*.jpg`; do cp $i newdir/201003${i:3}; done
```